# Cannot clone a repo from azure devops on Linux VM on windows 11 using ssh

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, ssh, azure-devops

I am trying to clone a repo from Azure DevOps on Linux VM on windows 11 using SSH. It is asking me for a username and password for https://XX.visualstudio.com. The steps are below. Am I missing anything?

- Created a VM Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using Hyper V
- Installed git
- Generated a key pair
- added a public key in Azure DevOps
- and git clone the repo

I was not able to create and edit ~/.ssh/config, it is not present, some solutions were suggested to edit it.

Comment: "*…using **SSH** … username and password for **https**…*" Hmm? "*I was not able to create and edit ~/.ssh/config, it is not present…*" You can create it but in your case it wouldn't help.

Comment: Are you sure you used the ssh clone url and not the https one?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure we are using SSH URL when cloning.

[image]

[image]

Enter your passphrase for SSH key.

[image]

For more details about how to generate a new SSH key and set passphrase, you could refer to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops